# How to run Joomla controller task with cron?

Tags: php, joomla, cron, joomla2.5

I am having one problem that how can I run the task defined in my component controller with cron at after some time interval. If someone has any suggestion how to do that please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its same as run the controller task via form action url like below.

```
index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=mycontroller.task_name
```

Normally you can set the action url of form like above or with hidden fields for `options,task,controller` separately.

The things that you can't do with cron in this case is administrator controller tasks,
Because it requires user login. So in such case you have to write those functions in a front end controller that can be access via url.

One security concern is you should include a key for your Cron Jobs like simple param `&key=someencrypetd_value` with the url, then decrypt and compare inside your controller task before starting the controller task functionality. This will help you to prevent someone executing your Cron via direct url.

For setting up the Cron Jobs just login to Cpanel->Cron Jobs->set your url.

here url should be full like `http://www.yourdomain.com/index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=mycontroller.task_name&key=yoursecretkey`

more about setting [Cron with Cpanel](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/CronJobs)

An example command will be look like follows.

```
wget -O /dev/null "http://www.yourdomain.com/index.php?option=com_users&view=registration&task=registration.UpdateAllShoppers&key=gdyr73501250"
```

Also time you can set like `Minute -0 , Hours - 0 , Day - *, Month -* ,Weekday -*` for executing this on all day at `12:00AM`

Comment: Is it applicable for linux sever as I can see there is field to define command, so how can i execute this?

Comment: Yes its applicable for Linux Servers, You just need to set the Cron on Cpanel and set the email option with yours and set time period when the Cron executed a report will send to the given email id.

Comment: So it means I can directly put this url to command section and set the further recommended settings.